# How to print an array originated from a brace expansion command in bash scripting?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, for-loop, brace-expansion

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=({1..$(wc mylist.txt | cut -d " " -f 3)})

for i in "${arr[@]}";
do
        echo $i;
done
```

Basically what i'm trying to do is set an array using a brace expansion command.

The command is:

`wc mylist.txt | cut -d " " -f 3`

In short what this command does is return the number of lines of a file, but it will bring other outputs that i don't need besides the actual number. So I use cut afterwards to get the actual number i need on the wc command, which in this case is 7.

So the brace expansion i use here (in my understanding) should bring me the number 1 to 7, like this:

`declare -a arr=({1..7})`

which should translate into a line like this:

`declare -a arr=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)`.

When i try to print this array, inside the for-loop block, i was hopping it would get me an output like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Instead this is what i'm getting:

```
{1..7}
```

**How can i get the right output?**

Comment: At first i thought the wc command returns a string and i needed an integer, so i already tried converting the whole comand to integer with: ```wc mylist.txt | cut -d " " -f 3 | bc``` but that didn't work. It was still returning {1..7}

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D

Comment: Try `arr=($(seq $(wc -l < mylist.txt)))`. `seq` isn't a standard utility but is available on many systems.

Comment: `declare -a arr=( $(awk '{print FNR}' mylist.txt) )`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you M. Nejat Aydin and markp-fuso. Both your suggestions worked.

`arr=($(seq $(wc -l < mylist.txt)))`

or

`declare -a arr=( $(awk '{print FNR}' mylist.txt) )`

Answer (score 0):

With some adjustments, your code may behave as expected.

#### Adjustments:

1. The `wc` command takes an `-l` option for line count.
2. The `cut` targets the first field of that `wc` command output.
3. Assign that value to a variable, but that's perhaps just a style issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
total=$(wc -l mylist.txt | cut -d " " -f 1)
declare -a arr=( $(seq 1 "$total") )

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
        echo "$i";
done
```

#### Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Brace expansion didn't work for me either.